# How to implement counter with buttons to a post in a polymorphic associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app where I can make post and create comments to them. And I need to implement 2 buttons (like and unlike) in my view to every post(tweet) and comment to this tweet. Also I have 2 routes to my likes: post and destroy: (all routes are here)

```
resource  :user_profiles, only: %i[edit update]
  resources :tweets
  resources  :comments, only: %i[create destroy]
  resources  :likes, only: %i[create destroy]

  root to: 'home#index'
```

But also I have polymorphic associations:

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :likable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
end

class Tweet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :likes, as: :likable
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :likes, as: :likable
  belongs_to :tweet
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I wrote some code in my tweet.preview

```
 <% if tweet.likes.find_by(user_id: current_user.id)%>
  <%= button_to 'Unlike', like_path(likable_id: tweet.id, likable_type: tweet.class.name, user_id: current_user.id), method: :delete %>
 <% else %>
   <%= button_to 'Like', likes_path(likable_id: tweet.id, likable_type: tweet.class.name, user_id: current_user.id), method: :post%>
 <% end %>
```

But I don't know how to implement like controller to count likes and display 2 buttons with counter to view.
My db.schema is here:

```
  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "content"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "tweet_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "likes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string "likable_type"
    t.integer "likable_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "tweets", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "content"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_tweets_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "user_profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "username"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.date "birthday"
    t.string "bio"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_user_profiles_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So i'm not sure about your setup. Are you using a gem?

So the secret to do this is to create two seperated paths:

```
    resources  :likes do
     member do
      get :like
      get :unlike
    end
   end
```

inside your controller, you can then execute the logic inside each method:

```
def like
 //find the user
 //follow the user
 //redirect him
end

def unlike
 //find the user
 //unfollow the user
 //redirect him
end
```

Also, you can then simply use your buttons for each like/unlike path:

```
 <% if tweet.likes.find_by(user_id: current_user.id)%>
  <%= button_to 'Unlike', likes_unlike_path(likable_id: tweet.id, likable_type: tweet.class.name, user_id: current_user.id), method: :delete %>
 <% else %>
   <%= button_to 'Like', likes_like_path(likable_id: tweet.id, likable_type: tweet.class.name, user_id: current_user.id), method: :post%>
 <% end %>
```

Now, to display the sizes of a like, you could retrieve the amount of users that have liked the tweet:

```
<h3>People who liked this tweet: <%= likes.count %> </h3>
```

obviously, only those people who have liked something will be displayed. If you also need a negative number, you could do two things: Either create a join table for your likes or add a new integer and call it "number_likes"

Then, inside your like method, simply increase the number_likes integer by 1. Whenvever someone clicks on the like link, the number will increase.

Inside the unlike method, simply substract by 1 whenever unlikes something. This should give you more or less the same result, but it would also allow you to add a negativ like number.

```
def like

number_likes += 1
//your previous logic here
end


def unlike
 number_likes -=1
end
```

in your view, you could then simply get the tweet.likes.number_likes to display the amount of likes.

If something is still unclear, let me know!

Happy coding!

Comment: I need to create additional field in my db to calculate likes?

Comment: Hey! Please double check my answer, there are two examples. The first one doesn't requires you to add any additional db records. The second example would only apply if you need more control, just like stated in the answer.

Comment: I have a problem to implement controller logic

Answer (score 0):

Well you just need to pass the parent of the future like record (whereas it is a post or a comment) to the create action of the like controller.

You need to add a link to your buttons such as : `like_path(parent_type: "comment", parent_id: @comment_id), method: "post"`

(here `@comment_id` may not be an instance variable, especially if you loop through all comment of a specific tweet, it may instead look like `comment.id` if in your loop you did something like `@tweet.comments.each do |comment|`)

Then in your like controller, you can just assign them to the record.

I assume here that the user id "is already known" and you create the like from the user record.

```
@like = current_user.likes.new(likable_id: params[:parent_id], likable_type: params[:parent_type])
@like.save
```

So most of the job is made in your view by creating the correct link for your different buttons...